# OSB 12c: pass json body with GET request

Tags: rest, osb

I need to call a GET REST service that expects json body but it seems that the latest version of OSB is not capable of doing that. I tried several ways:

1. Created REST service with WADL, manually added **representation** to GET **request** since the wizard didn't do it. Launched it from test console and the target service received a request with empty body
2. Created HTTP transport with text/plain content and changed both method and content-type header in pipeline; received 408 regardless on service called

The service itself is not subject to change.
Does anybody have a successful experience in calling such service from OSB 12c?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with current (12.2.1.4) version. Some services may also accept data in GET query string instead of body. In this case Native API may be used by setting http:query-string property of the outbound request.